# Find the number of functions $f:A\to B$ whose domain is $A$, such that $f$ is strictly increasing

Tags: functions

Let set $A=\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}$ and $B=\left\{-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5\right\}$.
Find the number of functions $f:A\to B$ whose domain is $A$, such that $f$ is strictly increasing.

---

I know the condition of strictly increasing function. If $x_1>x_2$, then $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$, then $f$ is strictly increasing function. But I cannot apply that here in counting the number of such functions here. Please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that a strictly increasing map $f \colon A \to B$ is uniquely determinend by its image. So there as many such maps as there are 5-subsets of the 8-set $B$, namely 
$$ \binom 85 = \frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}{3!} = 56. $$